# How to rename an Excel sheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a scenario where I wanted to change the name of a sheet in the spread-sheet.

1. I tried creating a spread-sheet using `ss = Workbook()`. I think this is creating the spread-sheet with a sheet named "Sheet".
2. I tried changing the name of the sheet using the below format:

   ```
   ss_sheet = ss.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
   ss_sheet.Name = 'Fruit'
   ```

But then the above step is not changing the sheet name as required. Is there anything wrong in the above step?

Comment: I think you have to do `ss_sheet.Save`. Are you using csc or openpyxl?

Comment: @AnnapoornimaKoppad: I am using opeynpyxl. I tried using 
ss_sheet.save, it says "AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'save'" and when I tried ss.save its not actually changing the sheet name [it retains the old sheet name 'Sheet'].

Comment: It should be `ss.save(file)`. Sorry for the earlier reply.

Comment: `ss_sheet.name = 'Fruit'`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `title` attribute:

```
import openpyxl

ss = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
#printing the sheet names
ss_sheet = ss['Sheet']
ss_sheet.title = 'Fruit'
ss.save("file.xlsx")
```

Comment: Also doesn't work if the another sheet in the same workbook also has that name, as you'd expect...

Comment: Also note that get_sheet_by_name is [now deprecated](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=get_sheet_by_name#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.get_sheet_by_name). Replace `ss_sheet = ss.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')` with `ss_sheet = ss['Sheet']` in the latest version.

Comment: I know this is old but if you do this and there are any links inside other sheets to 'Sheet' they will be broken.