# Export specific Sheet, and save different file openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to export a specific sheet from an excel file, but without a result. I want to export a specific sheet of paper to a completely new file What I have written is:

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Python\test.xlsx')
a = (book.get_sheet_names())
sheet1 = book[a[5]]
sheet1.save('C:\Python\sheet2.xlsx')
```

Also, another thing I can't do,and look for a certain sheet if I have its name.

I apologize if the questions are simple, but it's been a few days since I started with python :)

Comment: Have you already taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl)?

Comment: Razel, I've just posted a solution. Let me know if helps.

Comment: Worksheets do not have a save method so you cannot do this. Please spend some more time reading the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `openpyxl` does provide `copy_worksheet()` but it cannot be used between different workbooks. You can copy your sheet cell-by-cell or you can modify your starting workbook in memory and then you can save it with a different file name. Here is the code

```
import openpyxl

# your starting wb with 2 Sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheets = wb.sheetnames # ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']

for s in sheets:

    if s != 'Sheet2':
        sheet_name = wb.get_sheet_by_name(s)
        wb.remove_sheet(sheet_name)

# your final wb with just Sheet1
wb.save('test_with_just_sheet2.xlsx')
```

Comment: and automatically with the wb. remove_sheet command, remove all the sheets that I don't need?

Comment: Yes, it removes all the sheets except for the one named 'Sheet2' and it saves the `wb` in new file with just the sheet you need

Comment: Last request, if I have un nome del foglio "hello world1, hello world2, etc", and I have to create the file that only has the last part of the page name, so world1, world2, etc. How do I do it?  with[0:5] correct? As a result, the file name that I save is changed according to the name.

Comment: @Razel for example you could iterate over the remaining sheets and change their name like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540789/how-to-rename-the-sheet-name-in-the-spread-sheet-using-python)

Comment: Can i modify the same file usig Optimized mode i.e. write_only?

Comment: `write_only` is used for writing large files. It depends on what you want to do. Please, read warnings in this page https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html in order to understand if this fits your needs.