# Can someone explain why this happens when using openpyxl 2.6.2?

Tags: python, openpyxl

According to my understanding, `workbook.get_sheet_names()` is deprecated and we should use `wb.sheetnames` instead with `openpyxl` 2.6.2.

`wb.sheetnames` returns a `list` of all the sheets, so why can't we do this?

```
    import openpyxl
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx') #loading the workbook
    wb.sheetnames #getting the sheetnames with the new recomended code
    #output:['Sheet']
    wb.sheetnames[0]='Another name'
    wb.sheetnames[0] # Checking if it were changed or not
    #output:['Sheet']
```

Why didn't the above code work if `wb.sheetnames` acts as a `list`?
No error was displayed but I didn't see the expected changes

This is what `example.xls` looks like:

> ```
> A                         B             C
> 1 4/5/2015 13:34  Apples          73
> 2 4/5/2015 3:41   Cherries        85
> 3 4/6/2015 12:46  Pears           14
> 4 4/8/2015 8:59   Oranges         52
> 5 4/10/2015 2:07  Apples          152
> 6 4/10/2015 18:10 Bananas         23
> 7 4/10/2015 2:40  Strawberries    98
> ```

Comment: I am a new programmer and can work around this with changing the title attribute but i dont want to leave any gaps in my learning

Comment: Can you share example.xlsx?

Comment: Can you teach me how i am a beginner at this

Comment: You can use [gist](https://gist.github.com) or Google drive or just copy paste your data here in the question on SO. Will work

Comment: You need not have to link in comment, just edit it in the question above. It will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename the sheet name in the spread-sheet using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540789/how-to-rename-the-sheet-name-in-the-spread-sheet-using-python)

Comment: I mentioned above that i can work around this by using that format in ur suggested link

Comment: all i want is an explanation on why this code doesnt work and how the new wb.sheetnames operates

Comment: @JadAH will it be ok if I give you alternate solution using Pandas? it works

Comment: you can use the .get_sheet_by_name and the .title attributes but is there any way around it?

Comment: All i want is widening my perspective and understanding of old and new versions of openpyxl

Comment: and how excel sheets work in general im new to working with them

Comment: Worksheets are more than just their titles which is why you need to edit this specifically. `wb.sheetnames` tells you it is giving just a list of the sheet names, not the sheets themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to relevant [section of the docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html)

`wb.sheetnames` will return **list of strings (i.e. just the sheet names)**, `wb.sheetnames[0]` is just a string.
When you do `wb.sheetnames[0]='Another name'` you change the first string in the list returned by wb.sheetnames, but this change has no any practical/visible effect, because this list is not assigned to any variable.

there is also `wb.worksheets` which will return list of **sheet objects**. You can use this method access the respective sheet and using Worksheet.title property do
`wb.worksheets[0].title='New Title'`

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
print(wb.sheetnames)
print(type(wb.sheetnames[0]))
print(wb.worksheets) 
print(type(wb.worksheets[0]))
wb.worksheets[0].title='New Title'
print(wb.sheetnames)
print(wb.worksheets)
```

output

```
['Sheet']
<class 'str'>
[<Worksheet "Sheet">]
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
['New Title']
[<Worksheet "New Title">]
```

Note - for the example I am using new Workbook instance with just one sheet inside it

Answer (score 4):

It's because `sheetnames` is a *property*; in other words, it looks like an instance attribute, but when you access it, a function is in fact called. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) for more details.

Now, if we look at the `openpyxl` source, we can find the definition of `sheetnames`:

```
    @property
    def sheetnames(self):
        return [s.title for s in self._sheets]
```

`sheetnames` *creates and returns a new `list`* every time it is called, which you can prove with `id`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()

a = book.sheetnames
b = book.sheetnames

print(id(a) == id(b))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Due to this, you are in fact just modifying the first element of this new `list` that is created every time you call `sheetnames`.

Comment: the only way is to change the title attribbute directly